# How to set html page in phonegap app to be across whole screen?

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova

I am working on phonegap/cordova app. Created few pages in html5, but i can't get them to be across whole screen regardless of the size of the screen. I tried with javascript. Added this script to be activated on load:

```
function SetupPage(){
    document.getElementsById("container").style.width=window.innerWidth;
    document.getElementsById("container").style.height=window.innerHeight;
}
```

But it still has the size of content within it, and i need it to stretch everything depending on the screen size. How can this be done?

Comment: Responsive Web Design. Google it. (Make sure your meta viewport scale is correct, as indicated by Drew below.)

Answer (score 0):

set your meta viewport scale

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

You should be able to use CSS after that to size how you need.

Comment: It is set already, but container div is still the size needed for elements within and not the size of the screen.

Comment: why not use CSS to do the resizing?

Comment: So what should i put in css to get container to be across any screen?

Comment: Like @Kerri mentioned look into responsive web design. That will do the trick, generally #container{width:100%} also make sure your body and html are sized correctly.